# Обработка метода setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, adapter

Имеется ListView c Custom List Adapter. Как в примере http://javatechig.com/android/android-listview-tutorial

я использую обработчик для нажатия на items ListView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Log.d(TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = " + id);




            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Подскажите как мне забрать данные (TextView headlineView; TextView reporterNameView; TextView reportedDateView;) из адаптера в зависимости от нажатого item для того чтобы потом Intent передать в другую Activity. Или если можете дайте ссылку на реализованный пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`. Он вернет объект в вашем адаптере, нужно будет явно преобразовать к соответствующему типу.
Если действительно хотите данные из TextView, а не из объекта (но зачем?), то в onItemClick передается view. Можно использовать `view.findViewById()` для получения соответствующих TextView.